# Homeomorphism on $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ to itself with basis $B_n :=\{x\in X:x|n\}$

Tags: general-topology, functions, solution-verification

This was a bonus question on an exam in an introductory topology course I took that I couldn't figure out, but was still curious afterwards.

Let $X=\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ and let $\mathcal B$ be the basis for the topology on $X$ generated by sets of the form $B_n := \{x\in X: x|n\}$ for all $n\in X$. Give an example of a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ which is *not* the identity map, with respect to the topology generated by $\mathcal B$.

My thought:
$f(n)=
\begin{cases}
3, n=2\\
2, n=3\\
n, n\notin\{2,3\}
\end{cases}$.

This is clearly a bijection, so it suffices to show $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

**Please tell me if there are any errors in my reasoning, and if you have any other solutions which suffice (especially fun ones!)**

First notice that for any open $U\subseteq X$, we can write $U=\bigcup_{n\in I}B_n$ for some collection of basic open sets $B_n$. However, for straightforward reasons $U=B_m$ where $m$ is the least common multiple on all indices $n\in I$.  (Assume $I$ to be finite, otherwise we just recover all of $X$).

Let $U$ be an arbitrary open set. If $U=X$, then $f^{-1}(X)=X$, so we are done. Similarly, if $U=\emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, trivially open. Otherwise $U=B_n$ for some $n\in X$. If $n=2$, then $f^{-1}(B_2)=\{3\}=\{x\in X: x|3\}=B_3$ which is open. If $n=3$ then $f^{-1}(B_3)=B_2$, also open. Otherwise $n\geq 4$ and $f^{-1}(B_n)=B_n$, also open. Hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and a similar argument shows $f$ is continuous. Hence $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse, so $f$ is a homeomorphism. $\Box$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll repost the comments here.

- You can’t take $U=B_n$ necessarily, as $I$ the set of powers of two has $U=I\neq X$, for a number divides a power of two iff. it is itself a power of two. *But*, a function is continuous iff. it is continuous on the basic sets.
- Your function was not continuous, as $f^{-1}\{2,4,8\}=\{3,4,8\}$, which fails to be open as any $B_n$ containing $4$ must also contain the divisors of $4$, like $2$.

The last bullet point is actually very key. The openness criterion amounts intuitively to preserving divisibility properties: I envisaged the divisibility lattice structure, and that any homeomorphism $g$ must shift the *entire* structure to be continuous. No simple *finite* switch will do. Related: any homeomorphism must map composites to composites, primes to primes (why?).

We can make your example work as follows. Let $a,b\in X$ be two distinct prime numbers (like $2$ or $3$). Define a function $g$ as follows: every $n\in X$ has a unique representation as a product of primes: $$n=a^{n_0}b^{n_1}\prod_{p\text{ prime}\\p\notin\{a,b\}}p^{n_p}$$Where the $n_i\in\Bbb N_0$. Define: $$g(n):=b^{\color{red}{n_0}}a^{\color{red}{n_1}}\prod_{p\text{ prime}\\p\notin\{a,b\}}p^{n_p}$$So I have switched $a$ and $b$ but also every number with associated divisibility properties: I’ve switched the whole branches of the lattice corresponding to numbers containing $a$ and $b$ in the factorisation tree.

Examples:

> Concretely let $a=2,b=3$. Then $g(9)=g(3^2)=2^2=4$. $g(18)=g(9\cdot2)=(2^2)\cdot3=12$. $g(140)=g(2^2\cdot5\cdot7)=3^2\cdot5\cdot7=315$.

Clearly $g$ is self-inverse and bijective, so we only need to establish continuity. But $k|n$ iff. $g(k)|g(n)$ (why?) so this holds: $g^{-1}\{B_n\}=B_{g(n)}$. $g$ is a nontrivial homeomorphism and there are infinitely many of these. Such $g$ are also multiplicative functions! Side-note: I think *any* homeomorphism must have $k|n\iff g(k)|g(n)$ but I'm not completely sure yet. But I think my example is quite natural in this regard.

You can generalise this to a switch in $3$ primes, or more, using nontrivial permutations.